# How to use FIND_JNI on cmake

Tags: java-native-interface, cmake, hornetq

I'm trying to write a build for my project where I'm trying to replace autobuild, and I need to proper use FIND_JNI.

I could make a simple build but it's not properly finding jni.h

And I need to find a proper way (without a hack) to define the Java include as this needs to be portable to other users.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following code works for me. In your root `CMakeLists.txt` file add:

```
find_package(JNI)

if (JNI_FOUND)
    message (STATUS "JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message (STATUS "JNI_LIBRARIES=${JNI_LIBRARIES}")
endif()
```

Answer (score 3):

That solution did not worked for me, I used:

```
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)    
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

and

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

must return a valid path.

Comment: Note: if using CMake 3.24+, use the `JNI::JNI` target imported by `find_package(JNI REQUIRED)` (instead of old-school `*_INCLUDE_DIRS`): https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJNI.html

Comment: @JonasVautherin could you please show a full example of how to use the new version?

Comment: Well something like `target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE JNI::JNI)`