# jni.h No such file or directory during cmake linux?

Tags: java, c++, linux, opencv

I've been trying to make opencv for linux, I used the cmake parameters:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/include -D JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so -D JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/arm/server/libjvm.so -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
```

and it generated the files fine.

It was then into around the 81% when it was trting to generate the opencv-jar it opped up with

```
/home/pi/Desktop/opencv-3.1.0/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/common.h:8:17 fatal error jni.h No such file or directory
```

So I'm not sure what to be doing now with it. openjdk is installed properly too

Edit: I tried using the -I flag, by doing the command

```
make -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/includes
```

to no avail

Comment: Did you check the directory: $JAVA_HOME/include and make sure that there is the jni.h file exists?

Comment: @DilshodShaymanov yes it exists

Answer (score 0):

the `-I` flag on `make(1)` command only affects the files included in the makefile by the `.include` directive, not the directories searched for by the compiler.  For that purpose, just pass the `-I` flag to each compilation.  One way to do this is

```
$ make CFLAGS="-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/includes"
```

you can also pass the `CFLAGS` from the environment, as in

```
$ export CFLAGS=\""-I/usr/lib/..."\"  # escaped double quotes make them to be included in the string.
$ make
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67154438/1290868

[FindJNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715804/how-to-use-find-jni-on-cmake)

```
find_package(JNI)

if (JNI_FOUND)
    message (STATUS "JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message (STATUS "JNI_LIBRARIES=${JNI_LIBRARIES}")
endif()
```