# CMAKE add java libraries to cpp project

Tags: java, c++, cmake

I'm trying to build an app that can invoke java code from c++.

So that I could write something like this

```
#include<jni.h>
```

Then do something like this [How to access the Java method in a C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992836/how-to-access-the-java-method-in-a-c-application) 
I have problem adding libraries to CMakeLists.txt
Thats what I have now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(test_cpp_jni)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)    
include_directories("${JAVA_HOME}/include ${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux")

link_libraries(${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    main.cpp
    wrapper/WrapperJNI.cpp
    wrapper/WrapperJNI.h)


add_executable(test_cpp_jni ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(test_cpp_jni ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)
```

What shall I correct/add to make this work.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: After long time searching, I found solution!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715804/how-to-use-find-jni-on-cmake/7716814#7716814

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to solve your problem:

```
find_package(JNI)
    if (JNI_FOUND)
        include_directories(SYSTEM ${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH})
        include_directories(SYSTEM ${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2})
    endif()

if (JNI_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(<example> ${JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY})
endif()
```